# Homology of a CW complex with degree maps

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the standard CW complex of $S^1$ with two cells in each dimension. Suppose two $2$-cells are attached via degree $n$ and degree $m$ maps, respectively, where $n,m$ are nonzero (but not necessarily positive) integers. Compute the homology of the resulting CW complex and determine when such choices of $n,m$ are homotopy equivalent.

[image]

My work: It is easy to show, unless I have missed something, that $H_0\cong \mathbb{Z}=\langle v \rangle$ and $H_1\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\langle b-a \rangle$. Label the two cells $U$ and $V$. Say $U$ is attached by a degree $n$ map and $m$ via a degree $m$ map. Then I have $U \mapsto n(b-a)$ and $V \mapsto m(b-a)$. Writing the matrix and putting it in Smith Normal form, I find $H_2=\langle nv-mu \rangle=\mathbb{Z}$. Furthermore, if $n>2$, we have $H_n=0$. I believe all this work is correct.

Where I am unsure is the last part. Looking at $H_1$, if $(n,m)$ and $(n',m')$ are to produce the same homology groups, we must have $n=n'$. Is it sufficient to then say you can switch the roles of the generators and say then $m=m'$? All the work and computations I have done suggests that each unique pair $(n,m)$ produce unique homologies. I find this strange since I would expect the homology groups of $(n,m)$ to be the same as $(m,n)$ just by 'flipping' the space 'upside-down'. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EricWofsey Detaching myself a bit and reading, the question certainly was not clear. Hopefully, these latest edits make it easier for people to understand what I'm trying to do. However, the attaching maps are not specified, just that you are to take a CW complex for $S^1$ and attach two $2$-cells to the circle with degree $n$ and $m$ maps and then calculate the homology. The only way I could think to attach the maps was in the way I did in the problem. Should I be using $S^1=e_0 \cup e_2$ instead? I should think it would be possible both ways - even if more difficult one of the ways.

Comment: Ah, it makes much more sense now.  I got caught up on trying to understand where $S^2$ was coming from.